# Finding the mode of an array?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop

I seem to be having trouble with my code because it's not printing correctly. I'm trying to find the mode of an array using another method we created for class.

For example, an array with the elements {4,4,4,5,5}, prints the mode as 5 instead of 4. Why is that?

```
public static int mode(int[] numbers) {
    int winner = 0;


    for(int i=1; i<numbers.length; i++){
        winner = numbers[0];
        if ( occr(numbers,numbers[i]) == occr(numbers,numbers[i-1]) ){
            winner = numbers[i];}

        else if( occr(numbers,numbers[i]) > occr(numbers,numbers[i-1]) ){
            winner = numbers[i];}

        else if( occr(numbers,numbers[i]) < occr(numbers,numbers[i-1]) ){
            winner = numbers[i-1];}
    }
    return winner;
    }



public static int occr(int[] numbers, int x){
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if(numbers[i] == x){
            counter++; }
    }
    return counter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code is incorrect.

At each iteration i of your for loop, you set the winner as only numbers[i], numbers[i-1], or numbers[0]. This is incorrect, as you should be preserving your winner variable.

You also perform a lot of unnecessary calls to the occr function. 
You need only call the occr function at most once for every index within you array.

```
int winner = numbers[0];
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
  int value = occr(numbers, numbers[i]);
  if(value > winner)){
     winner = value;
  }
}
return winner;
```

Comment: if(value > winner) method won't work though right because what if you have an array with {4,4,5,5,5} ? 3 < 5 & the mode would be 4 instead of 5?